# How to save ManagedObjectContext at regular intervals? Currently dropping 1/3 of objects added

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm trying to save the MOC at intervals of 1000, however the below code just seems to miss some of them. This only saved 2/3 of the objects, the rest just seemed to disappear into the abyss. This seems like such a cludgy way to achieve this, so if anyone can suggest a better way I'd love to hear it.

This method is also taking about 9 minutes to add 115,000 objects. Is there anything I can do to improve this? Thanks.

```
dispatch_async(backgroundDispatchQueue,{

 NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundThreadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
 [backgroundThreadContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
 [backgroundThreadContext setUndoManager:nil];


 [products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


   NSManagedObject* newProduct;
   newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundThreadContext];

   [newProduct setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"name"];
   [newProduct setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_codes"] forKey:@"codes"];

   if ([product valueForKey:@"information"] == (id)[NSNull null]){
                                   // No information, NULL
     [newProduct setValue:@"" forKey:@"information"];
   } else {
     NSString *information = [product valueForKey:@"information"];
     [newProduct setValue:information forKey:@"information"];

   }

   if ([product valueForKey:@"megaimportant"] == (id)[NSNull null]){
                                       // No information, NULL
     [newProduct setValue:@"" forKey:@"megaimportant"];
   } else {
     NSString *megaimportant = [product valueForKey:@"megaimportant"];
     [newProduct setValue:megaimportant forKey:@"megaimportant"];

   }

   if ((self.productDBCount % 1000) == 0){
     NSLog(@"SAVE ME");
     NSError *error;

     if(![backgroundThreadContext save:&error])
     {
       NSLog(@"There was a problem saving the context (add/update). With error: %@, and user info: %@",
         [error localizedDescription],
         [error userInfo]);
     }
   } else if ((self.productDBCount + 1) == self.totalCount){
     NSLog(@"Final Save");

     NSError *error;

     if(![backgroundThreadContext save:&error])
     {
       NSLog(@"There was a problem saving the context (add/update). With error: %@, and user info: %@",
         [error localizedDescription],
         [error userInfo]);
     }
   }



   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
   {

    self.productDBCount = self.productDBCount + 1;
    float progress = ((float)self.productDBCount / (float)self.totalCount);
    int percent = progress * 100.0f;
    self.downloadUpdateProgress.progress = progress;
    self.percentageComplete.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", percent];
    NSLog(@"Added / updated product %f // ProductDBCount: %i // Percentage progress: %i // Total Count: %i", progress, self.productDBCount, percent, self.totalCount);

    NSDate *currentProcessedDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeSinceStarted = [currentProcessedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startProcessing];
    NSInteger remainingProcesses = self.totalCount - self.productDBCount;
    float timePerProcess = timeSinceStarted / (float)self.productDBCount;
    float remainingTime = timePerProcess * (float)remainingProcesses;
    self.timeRemaining.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ETA: %0.0f minutes %0.0f seconds", (((float)remainingTime - fmodf(remainingTime, 60.0f))/60), fmodf(remainingTime, 60.0f)];

    if (self.productDBCount == self.totalCount){

      [self updatesCompleted:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"last_updated"]];
    }

                                                 });
}];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of the block that you schedule on the background queue you asynchronously schedule another block on the main queue. There you increment your self.productDBCount. But at the same time you're using this property on the background queue.

So your background block on the next iteration of the loop can get not incremented value (because the block on the main queue has not been executed yet) and make wrong decisions about it. Even worse, if this property is declared as nonatomic, it can even get a corrupted value (although making it atomic won't solve this race condition anyway).

Try to replace asynchronous call with a synchronous one: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`

To make the import easier on the memory you might also want to reset the context after the save of each batch. But you need to make sure that you don't use any objects that you created on this context after the reset.

If you want to see what takes most of the time during import, run it in Instruments. I can recommend combination of Core Data instruments with Time Profiler instrument. Core Data instruments are available only in simulator.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to Sync has stopped it dropping the records. I'll have a look at the instrument tools for CoreData.

Comment: The first save takes 3500, the following saves take from 25000 - 31000. Don't suppose you have any idea what might be causing the drastic jump in save time?

Comment: 25000–31000 microseconds? Maybe not so bad. Are you sure it is the -save: method that occupies most of the time?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it to me (RE: http://i.imgur.com/Gy5bqUG.png). I'm not sure why it suddenly jumps after the first one.

Comment: Which most expensive methods does Timer Profiler show for the import?

Comment: I'm not too sure where to find that out.

Comment: Run with Time Profiler instrument. Then the easiest is to check all checkboxes on the left (those checkboxes that start with Separate by Thread). You'll see the list of most expensive method calls. Double-click any of them to go to the source code and see the percentage of expensive calls inside the particular method.